How RTTI knows class of an object in runtime for polymorphic types?
The following C++ code:
struct B
{
     virtual ~B() {}
};

struct D : B {};

int main()
{
    B* b = new D;

    cout << typeid(*b).name() << endl;
}

prints: 1D
So, typeid found that pointer of base class type B actually points to derived class D.
AFAIK, RTTI is stored in the constant memory of the process for every class.
I also know that the vtable of each class only stores pointers to virtual function of this class (or maybe I am wrong and the vtable also stores RTTI?)
So, for polymorphic class RTTIs, is there a table with the key pointer to vtable and value typeinfo?

That would be implementation specific, but I would expect it to be part of the vtable so that downcast will work.

It's an implementation detail, but it seems like you already know the answer, so what's the question?

Side note: nothing in this code needs the extra stuff that std::endl does. Use '\n' to end a line unless you have a good reason not to.

All it takes is a circle of standing stones, a unicorn horn (doesn't even need to be removed from the unicorn), and a ritual performed by a Level 14 wizard skilled in elf magic.

std does not specify how RTTI or even runtime polymorphism is implemented. VTABLE is only the most common practice, but there are alternatives too. In effect RTTI is no different from runtime polymorphism; just a few more hidden entries in the set of virtual functions, but the only accessor is class std::type_info constructed by keyword type_id.

"vtables" contain more than just an array of function pointers.
To solve some casting problems, you end up having to do the equivalent of a string compare on the type names involved.  This is especially true if you want two classes from different dlls to be able to interoperate with the same shared types.  (Which is a reason why you want to use anonymous namespaces for type versioning).
Here you can see the mangled name of the type being pulled out of the vtable pointer.
